# Send a message with rxjs webSocket on each new connection

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs

Using [rxjs/webSocket](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket), how do I send a login message on each new connection? Seems that the simplest way to do it would be using [WebSocketSubjectConfig](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/WebSocketSubjectConfig), hook on to the `openObserver`, dig out the underlying webSocket from `event.target` and send the login message. Is it recommended? Is there a better way? (using angular, but I don't think it matters).

Here's my code:

```
ws = webSocket({
    url: "wss://example.com",      
    openObserver: {
      next: (e) => e.target.send("login-info")          
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webSocket(config).multiplex(() => 'login-info', () => null, () => true)` to create a multiplexed WebsocketSubject which sends a message on subscription.

This feature was originally intended to support multiple streams/topics on one single Websocket, but I think it's fine to use it for your use-case as well.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use the multiplex subscribtion message to send the login credentials, how will I send the actual subscribtion message. These are two different things, the login is per websocket connection, and each channel has its own subscribtion message,